# keeping session state with generators instead of FSM in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to write some asyncio code that holds session state for multiple users/connections.

Here is a little toy example:

```
Please tell me your name:
asd
how old are you?
40
asd is 40 years old
```

The best way I think this could be implemented is like a generator function:

```
class MessageReciever():
    async def start_conversation(user_id):
         await send_message(user_id, "Please tell me your name")
         name = await wait_for_reply(user_id)
         await send_message(user_id, "how old are you?")
         age = await wait_for_reply(user_id)
         await send_message(user_id, "{} is {} years old".format(name, age)
```

Currently, I only have a function `async on_message(user_id, message)` that gets called every time a message is recieved. This is fine for all things I have now, which are stateless.

This ideal approach raises many issues:

- I do not know how to await() an event that is triggered by my own code.
- I do not know how to timeout the conversation if it takes too long. I don't want to keep the sessions in RAM forever, and there does not seem to be an easy way of ending a running coroutine or purging it to a DB.

The typical way of solving this would be writing a FSM, and keeping the state for each user in a separate structure, however writing and debugging a large FSM is very annoying, especially when prototyping. I don't need any loops in the FSM either.

How could I implement a simple way to keep stateful "conversations" in asyncio?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question?

Comment: sure, I wrote some very ugly code for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to stop thinking about events and callbacks and think about having threads instead. Except, unlike ordinary threads, which can interrupt your program at any time to switch to a different thread, your threads can only be interrupted when you use `await` to call something.

In this model, you would tend to keep a lot of your local state on the stack, unless you have state you needed to share between threads. And then you should make sure that it isn't left in an inconsistent state when you make an `await` call.

If you need to launch a new thread, use the appropriate call for the library/framework you're using. For `asyncio`, that would be `asyncio.ensure_future` (which isn't a good name). If you need to communicate between threads, use an inter-thread (well, inter-these-weird-threadlike-things) queue. For `asyncio` that would be an `asyncio.Queue`. I would recommend always specifying a max queue size when you do that to avoid some case where one thread sends a huge amount of stuff to another thread before the other thread gets to read it off the queue.

The inter-'thread' queue class will have an `await`able `put` and `get` method so the threads can pause if the queue is full and wait for it to empty a bit before sending more.

If you think about things this way, the correct way to write your program will occur naturally to you.

To answer your question about how to wait on one of your own events, just use an inter-'thread' queue and post your event to that and have the thing that would wait for it read from that queue.

The `asyncio` module also has a way to timeout an `await`. Do this:

await asyncio.wait_for(thing_to_timeout, 10) # Wait 10 seconds before returning regardless.

it will throw an `asyncio.TimeoutError` if the time expires before the `thing_to_timeout` comes back with an answer.